# Connected to wifi but no internet access

Tags: 14.04, wireless, network-manager

I am using `wpa_supplicant` to manually connect to wifi after deleting `network-manager` on Ubuntu 14.04.

Now that I've finally managed to connect, I can't access any pages on the internet and I can't ping anything either. This wifi and my network adapter (usb wireless dlink) work perfectly since I was using that setup 2 days ago before removing `network-manager`.

I know its an improvement because just yesterday Ubuntu took 2-3 minutes to boot because it told me it couldn't find network settings until it timed out eventually. Now it boots normally so it does see it and I feel I'm a few commands away.

Here's the setup :

[image]

Now the `iwconfig` before connecting to the wifi manually

[image]

and the `iwconfig` after connecting manually  (Chouchoune is my home network)

[image]

`lshw -C network`:

[image]

`route -n; cat /etc/resolv.conf; ping -c4 4.2.2.2; cat /etc/network/interfaces`

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `route -n; cat /etc/resolv.conf; ping -c4 4.2.2.2; cat /etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @Alaa Ali  Ive added the result of that command to the second edit. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By looking at my last input I realised that even though I was connected it couldn't resolve the name servers. I added `name-servers` to `/etc/network/interfaces` and made it point to my gateway address.

I finally resolved and I now have internet access.

Comment: Yup, that was one thing, but I think you must've also put a `gateway <gateway_IP>` entry in `/etc/network/interfaces` to add aroute.